# On the definition of a direct image of sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I'm confunsed by the definition of direct image of  sheaf which says

Let $f :X \rightarrow  Y $ be a continuous map of topological spaces, and let $\mathcal{F}$ be sheaf on $X$. Then there is a sheaf on $Y$ given by
$(f_{*} \mathcal{F})(V)=\mathcal{F}(f^{-1}(V))$, where $V$ is an open subset of $Y$.

But $(f^{-1}(V))=U$, and $U$ in an open subset of X. The problem is we will get a sheaf on $X$, not on $Y$. A sheaf on $Y$ should be  defined  on some open subset  of Y and gives as some nice function(holomorphic,....) on that open subset, but here by that definition  we get $\mathcal{F}(U)$ which is a collection of functions on $U$   and they  have no relation  with functions on $V$!

Can some one explain why this definition is true, or give an example to make it clear?

Comment: It sounds like you believe that sheaves are necessarily sheaves of functions, i.e. that $\mathcal{F}(U)$ should be a set of "nice" functions with domain $U$. No modern treatments of sheaf theory require this assumption, but some introductory material may not include any examples of sheaves which are not (in any way) sheaves of functions. This is a failure on their part—in order to understand modern sheaf theory, it is necessary to consider sheaves which are not sheaves of functions

Answer (score 5):

Let me bring you two pictures that maybe help you to understand the situation[image]

Sorry it is written in spanish but the text is not the important part of the image. This is a picture I drawn in order to understand the sheaf of regular function over an afin algebraic variety (algebraic geometry). In these example $V$ and $W$ are varieties that are topological spaces with Zariski topology. And sheaf brings open subsets to the set of regular functions over it that is, in fact, a K-algebra. (K algebraic close field where our varieties are defined)
[image]

About your question I think this second picture will be usefull to sum up that your sheaf is in $Y$ (It corresponds to $W$ on the picture) because to every open on $W$ you have and image across the sheaf even though you have to pass across $V$ (or $X$ in you case) to obtain this image.

The relation lack you claimed is hidden on your continous function $f$ in your case and $\varphi$ on my case.

-Notation changes I have used;

.$X=V$, $Y=W$

.$\mathscr F$ = $\mathcal O_{V}$ for sheafs notation

.$f$=$\varphi$ for continous function between your topological spaces

Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1):

Just like you said, we need to assign open set $V$ of $Y$ some set or abelian group or whatever. Let do sets here. So what set are we assigning to $V$? We are assigning this set:
$$\mathcal{F}(f^{-1}(V))$$
Is this a set? Yes it is. If I give you an open set $V$ of $Y$, can you tell me what the above set is? Yes because you know what $\mathcal{F}$ is. So, this indeed defines a sheaf on $Y$ (You need to check the sheaf definitions, but that's not what your question is about).

As an example, consider a topological space $X$, and a point $p \in X$. Consider $\{p\}$ as a space with only one point. Let $S$ be a set and let $\underline{S}$ be the constant sheaf on $\{p\}$. Let $f: \{p\} \rightarrow X$ be just the inclusion. Then we can do the direct image sheaf. For any open set $V$ in $X$, if $V$ contains $p$ that $f^{-1}(V) = \{p\}$, and if not $f^{-1}(V)$ is empty. So the direct image sheaf would be
$$f_{*}\underline{S}(V) = S \text{ or } \{?\}$$
where $\{?\}$ is any singleton set. This is the skyscraper sheaf on $X$ at $p$.

Comment: Can you give me an example

Comment: Is thinking of a sheaf on  a open set of a topological space X is a 
collection  the functions on that open set?

Comment: @Abdallahchaibeddrraa See the edits for an example. Well yes but it's more abstract than that. In general, I don't think you can talk about the values of elements in a section at a particular point on that open set.